# Non-whitespace before first tag

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I got this error while doing

```
ionic prepare android and ionic prepare ios.
```

I'm trying to remove platform from the project to re-add it, but this showing the same error "Non-whitespace before first tag".

Have you any idea of how I can solve this?

I'm using ionic 1.2 and cordova 6.5.0.

> Error: Non-whitespace before first tag.
>       Line: 0
>       Column: 1
>       Char: 9
>       at error (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/sax/lib/sax.js:667:10)
>       at strictFail (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/sax/lib/sax.js:693:7)
>       at beginWhiteSpace (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/sax/lib/sax.js:967:7)
>       at SAXParser.write (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/sax/lib/sax.js:1022:11)
>       at Parser.exports.Parser.Parser.parseString (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/xml2js/lib/xml2js.js:503:31)
>       at Parser.parseString (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/xml2js/lib/xml2js.js:7:59)
>       at Object.exports.parseString (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/xml2js/lib/xml2js.js:535:19)
>       at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/ionic-app-lib/lib/config-xml.js:21:12
>       at tryToString (fs.js:447:3)
>       at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (fs.js:434:12)

Answer (score 2):

The issue for me was when i lost power on my pc as i was building the app for android, i tried everything nothing worked until i checked my config.xml where i found it was in gibish i couldnt read anything from it. luckly i had a git backup so i restored my config.xml file and all was good again.

Answer (score 2):

**> cordova.cmd build android
Non-whitespace before first tag.
Line: 0
Column: 1
Char:**

> ionic cordova platform rm android
>
> ionic cordova platform add android@latest